# HP ProLiant G6 w/ P410i controller not recognizing ST1000NX0363 drive

Tags: hp-proliant, hardware-raid, sas

I've purchased a new Seagate ST1000NX0363 HDD for my HP ProLiant DL360 G6 Rackmount server. I've installed the drive into one of the hot-swap bays, but unfortunately the P410i controller doesn't seem to be able to recognize the new drive. The drive is definitely the right size, and its SFF-8482 SAS connector fits quite snugly into the backplane. Additionally, I have tested the new drive on all four hot-swap bays, and none of them work, so I am pretty sure that the problem isn't physical. It's also worth noting that I have updated the system to the latest firmware (2015/06/05).

Has anybody seen this sort of issue before? Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: A lot of enterprise hardware RAID controllers have white lists of supported devices so they don't have to deal with support calls from people buying random parts from who knows where.  I'd be surprised if that wasn't your issue.

Answer (score 1):

That hard disk is [worth more](http://www.provantage.com/seagate-st1000nx0363~7SEG90EY.htm) than [that old server](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-Proliant-DL380-G6-8-Core-Server-16GB-RAM-2x146GB-P-410-1PS-4-PORT-NIC-/172096963331?hash=item2811c74303:g:YN0AAOSwll1Wu5jc)!

But seriously, this is a 12Gbps SAS disk using advanced format, and the DL380 G6 predates your drive by ~6 years. Things might work, but you should really be using HP 900GB SAS drives.

But let's focus on why you say that the disk is not recognized. What have you actually tried?

- Did you try to create a logical drive?
- Are you using the HP storage BIOS utility?
- Are you using the HP Smart Storage Administrator?
- Please elaborate on "none of them work"... Since you have to actually configure a logical drive before a disk connected to a Smart Array controller becomes usable.